# Swap is being used 3% inspite of swappines=100 causing freezes

Tags: 18.04, freeze, swap

I have a two year old machine with 4GB memory. While using Kdenlive for editing or just a lot of tabs on firefox; my system freezes and requires a hard reset. On system monitor I noticed that freezes occur when memory reaches 100%. Even though Swappiness is at 100. Swap is barely used. Can I sort this out? Or is it a hardware issue?[image: System monitor screenshot now]

Answer (score 0):

The default swappiness is 60. I would avoid extremes like 1% or 100%.

You can limit Firefox RAM usage on this screen accessed by `Preferences` -> `Performance` -> `Content Process Limit`:

[image: Firefox RAM.png]

The default setting is `4`. You can reduce RAM impact by setting it to `2`. Performance will slow but RAM consumption will reduce. I have too much RAM so I set it to `7` (the maximum).